# C++ Static Class member refers to self

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm curious as to whether this is something that I can do:

```
using namespace tthread;
class E_thread {
    static std::list<E_thread*> all_threads;
    thread th;
    E_messageQueue queue;
public:
    E_thread(void (*threadFunction)(void *), void * threadFuncArg) {
        all_threads.push_back(this);
        th = thread(threadFunction,threadFuncArg);
    }
    ~E_thread() {
        queue.push_terminate_thread_message();
        th.join();
        all_threads.remove(this);
    }
};
```

My intention is to make it easy for any thread to spawn new threads or to send messages to another thread, and the thread list also is capable of cleaning up after itself. As far as I understand it I could replace `all_threads` with a global `std::list<E_thread*>` which serves the same purpose if I wanted to, but isn't this a cleaner method of getting that sort of "globalness"?

What's a little uneasy about this is that I haven't forced my new threads to have a message reading loop, to be able to handle the terminate message.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Is this a sane thing for me to do? Did you read my code and barf? Or was it a warm, fuzzy feeling?

Comment: Anything is better than a global, so... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fine, mostly. You need to protect access (reading or modifying both) to `all_threads` with a mutex of some sort. Also, you would be better served to use a `::std::set` if you destroy threads often during the course of your program.

Also, I sort of question having global variables of any kind. I think it would be cleaner if you had a 'thread manager' object that you passed in what you created a thread, or maybe a thread factory that kept track of all the threads it created.

Global variables make programs much harder to test, and make them more brittle and less capable of being modified later.

Comment: I missed the part where I still actually need to allocate my all_threads, presumably as a global! This is much uglier than I originally thought.

Comment: @Steven Lu: Make the factory a parameter that gets passed into a thread.

Answer (score 1):

- undefined behaviour on some OS if multiple threads attempt to join the same thread
- `all_threads` needs to be protected by a mutex for the `push_back`, `remove`, and any other reader that may try to iterate over it

  - you may want to include modifications to `th` in the mutex-protected block if other threads iterating `all_threads` may try to do something to `th` before or during its assignment
- this has a tendency to serialise thread destruction, as `push_terminate_thread_message` is sent to a single thread, then a `join` is done.  It's generally better to send all the termination messages then do all the `joins`.
- it's not obvious to me how the threads are supposed to know about the queues, though the `threadFuncArg` might be abused for this in some limited circumstances

Omnifarious's suggestion of a proper thread pool is much more appealing.

Comment: Any tips/rules of thumb for me to keep in mind as I design the thread pool?

Comment: My factory won't know if a thread exited. I wouldn't want to keep a pointer to the factory for each thread just for this purpose, would I?

Comment: On rereading, I see Omnifarious actually suggested a thread factory whereas I've suggested a pool.  Can only decide which is better in the context of a specific application usage.  For a pool, you do want the management object to track all the created threads, as well as allocate them more work as they finish their tasks.  If the pool is asked to shut down it should broadcast shutdown messages to all the threads it manages then join them all.  If you don't understand condition variables already, learn/experiment with them (or an OS-specific equivalent) before attempting the pool.

Comment: My factory is more like your pool since I envisioned it keeping track of all the threads that had been created.